# Error during load of log files in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am trying to open a project  in VB6.0 but while opening it gives me the following error:

```
Errors during load. Refer to 'D:\Forms\SHFa\Navigation.log' for details.
```

When i opened the log file this was the text in it:

```
Line 35: Class TGSCloseButton.TGSClose of control cmdClose was not a loaded control class.
```

I searched on the web for solutions but dint find any useful ones.
What should i do to solve this error?
I have also registered OCX files related to the solution.

Comment: Can you open the .vbp file for this project in notepad and post the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a lot i found out that  "LTOCX80N.OCX" was creating the problem.
The OCX file was not getting registered hence from the dependency walker i found out the required dll files which were missing.The dll files those were missing were:

```
1)LTEFX80N.DLL
2)LTFIL80N.DLL
3)LTIMG80N.DLL
4)LTKRN80N.DLL
5)LTTWN80N.DLL
```

I downloaded and registered those files and the error during load of log files were gone.Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

#### If it's a component:

In the VB6 IDE, press `CTRL+T` to bring up the `Components` dialog. Check the box next to `Selected Items Only`. Find one that says `(missing)` or some other error. If you click it in the list to select it, it should show the OCX/DLL file name underneath the list.

#### If it's a reference:

The same procedure needs to be done except you need to go to the `Projects` menu and then click `References...` to bring up the list of references. Find ones that are checked and say they are missing.

From either of these dialogs you can click a `Browse...` button to locate the actual OCX/DLL file(s) that you said you already installed, click `OK`, close all instances of the IDE, reopen the project and bring the `References` or `Components` dialog back up to see if it is resolved.

Comment: I opened the references window in my solution and found that a dll was missing.Hence i added it, closed the solution and reopened the project.The reference for the dll is now added in the project but im still getting the .log file error for the forms that are created in the project..